# Is data-equalTo reserved or unable to be selected by jQuery/Sizzle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I was trying to wire up the jQuery Validator plugin to work with data attributes instead of direct attributes (examples: data-minlength instead of minlength, data-equalTo instead of equalTo) so that my markup would validate as valid HTML5. Everything was working great until I got to data-equalTo.  I ended up having to use data-equals instead and put a special condition in my code:

```
$("#form").validate();
['minlength', 'maxlength', 'range', 'min', 'max', 'equals' /* 'equalTo' no worky! */].forEach(function (item) {
    $('input[data-' + item + ']').each(function () {
        if ($(this).data(item)) {
            var rule = {};
            if (item == 'equals') /* special condition because 'equalTo' never makes it into this if block */
                rule['equalTo'] = $(this).data(item);
            else
                rule[item] = $(this).data(item);
            $(this).rules("add", rule);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem seemed to be with the `$('input[data-' + item + ']')` selector. For whatever reason it was not selecting for data-equalTo. Is it reserved, or unable to be selected via jQuery for some reason?

---

Now working based on Yoshi's feedback:

```
['minlength', 'maxlength', 'range', 'min', 'max', 'equalTo'].forEach(function (item) {
    $('input[data-' + item + ']').each(function () {
        var lowerItem = item.toLowerCase();
        if ($(this).data(lowerItem)) {
            var rule = {};
            rule[item] = $(this).data(lowerItem);
            $(this).rules("add", rule);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery, you'll have to access the data-attributes in lowercase. In your case:

```
$(somelement).data('equalto');
```

and if that is unwanted, try [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(somelement).attr('data-equalTo');
```

though, you'll not get the auto-parsing from jquery in that case.

---

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BS6wy/1/

```
<div id="foo" data-equalTo="42"></div>​

<script>
  console.log(
    $('#foo').data('equalTo'), // undefined
    $('#foo').data('equalto'), // 42 (as number)
    $('#foo').attr('data-equalTo')  // "42" (as string)
  );​
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to work around it based on your feedback. Question updated with new code.